# Merging Angular 6 based web pages with legacy ASP.NET web portal

Tags: asp.net, angular, integration

I have a **.NET 4.0** based plain **ASP.Net** legacy Web Portal. Now, i have some new requirements for which i am planning to use **Angular 6**. Rewriting existing .NET based web app to Angular 6 would require huge effort. So, I am thinking to create new pages in Angular 6 and integrate with existing ASP.NET application. Before trying this approach, i want some suggestions on how to integrate ASP.NET server side application with Angular client side pages.

Sharing your experiences on similar approach, suggestions, recommendations are always welcome.

Comment: Your best bet is to use angular element (web component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Angular is a SPA or single page application style of development where ASP.Net legacy renders a new page with every post back operation which will destroy an Angular app instance. Any time you need to navigate to pages in the APS.Net app you will lose your Angular app and need to reinitialise it every time you route back to anew page.

Maybe you could iframe the old pages and hide the Angular SPA each time you show an old page so you can keep the SPA running.